# Secondary Temperature

Tags: secondary-fermentation

I'm considering racking my brew to a secondary FV once fermentation is complete to allow the yeasts to clean up the beer but I'm not sure if I need to maintain the same heat as I did in the primary?  Some things I've read suggest the temperature should be as low as 10 degrees Celsius but others suggest warmer.  I figured the lower temperature would be ideal for clearing the beer but wouldn't it make the yeast go dormant and prevent them cleaning up the beer?

I'm only considering transferring as I only have the ability to keep one FV at the required temperature and want to get another brew on. :)

Answer (score 1):

In order for the yeast to be of much help to you, you want the beer to stay in the primary vessel.  If you are looking for the beer to clear from a visibility standpoint, you can start lowering the temp in the primary as well.  Moving to a secondary to do this is largely unnecessary.  But if you were really concerned you could move it off the yeast cake for an extended storage period.  Might as well package the beer at that point.

Don't chill to quickly as that can cause shock to the yeast giving off more flavor compounds that you may or may not like.

Comment: Thanks.  If I chill it I was just going to turn off my heat source, as the bucket is in water it should take a while to cool down.